# ASP.NET MVC Application Identity does not share with ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, .net-core

I have an ASP.Net Core 2 project which i set all Authentication Configuration

in ASP.Net Core 2 Preview2\Start.cs

```
var protectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\SharedFolder"));
var dataProtector = protectionProvider.CreateProtector(
                                    "CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
                                    "Cookie",
                                    "v2");
var ticketFormat = new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector);
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
services.AddAuthentication(o =>{
                        o.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        o.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;                    
                    });
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(c => {
                    c.CookieName = "myapplication";               
                    c.ExpireTimeSpan =  TimeSpan.FromDays(3);
                    c.CookieSecure = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
                    c.SlidingExpiration = true;
                });
```

in ASP.Net MVC4 \ **ConfigureAuth** function:

```
var protectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\SharedFolder"));
var dataProtector = protectionProvider.CreateProtector(
                    "CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
                    "Cookie",
                    "v2");
var ticketFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(new DataProtectorShim(dataProtector));
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions{
                AuthenticationType = "Cookie",
                AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
                CookieName = "myapplication",
                CookieDomain = "localhost",
                TicketDataFormat = ticketFormat,
                CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager()
            });
```

share Cookies works properly i set cookie in Asp.Net Core2 Project and i read it form MVC Project and verse versa correctly, put when i check User IsAuthenticated always get false in MVC Project.

How can i get the user Identiy in MVC Project? Any help is more than welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by commit a few lines in ASP.Net Core 2 Preview2\Start.cs

```
/*services.AddAuthentication(o =>{
                        o.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        o.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;                    
                    });*/
```

and i changed ConfigureApplicationCookie to

```
 services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(c =>
            {
                c.CookieName = "myapplication";
                c.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(3);
                c.SlidingExpiration = true;
                c.CookieDomain = "localhost";
                c.TicketDataFormat = ticketFormat;
            });
```